# How to add poll code to the django-cms url.py file?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django-cms but I couldn't add the poll URL code to the url.py file. I follow every step in the Django-cms documentation but I still couldn't succeed can anyone help me with it.

This the documentation of the Django-cms:

[integrating_applications](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/03-integrating_applications.html)

" Install the application from its GitHub repository using pip:
pip install git+http://git@github.com/divio/django-polls.git#egg=polls
Let’s add this application to our project. Add 'polls' to the end of INSTALLED_APPS in your project’s settings.py (see the note on The INSTALLED_APPS setting about ordering ).

Add the poll URL configuration to urlpatterns in the project’s urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    re_path(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    re_path(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    re_path(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

Note that it must be included before the line for the django CMS URLs. django CMS’s URL pattern needs to be last, because it “swallows up” anything that hasn’t already been matched by a previous pattern. "

I had added the "polls" in the setting into the installation app code. But---
My question is where or how will put this code to the urls.py file. -- my urls.py file looks like this:

```
from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.urls import include, path

admin.autodiscover()



urlpatterns = [path("sitemap.xml", sitemap, {"sitemaps": {"cmspages": CMSSitemap}}),]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls), 
    path("", include("cms.urls"))
    )

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please markdown copy-pasted documentation as quotations and separate it from your own code and questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("", include("cms.urls"))
    )
```

It will include all the sub-urls that are listed in your other `polls/urls.py` file under the "mywebsite/polls/" URL. This is the standard Django way to organize your routes: per app.

Comment: why did you delete the re_ from the path?

Comment: path and re_path are two different methods to integrate a path. re_path use regular expressions, thus you can create more complex rules about the URLs. Use whichever you want, but if you use re_path you have to write a regular expression inside.

Comment: It is not working showing this error please help boss.. ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from 'cms' (C:\Users\DP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\cms\__init__.py)